# GSAP / TweenMax disable desktop animation on mobile and vise versa and also reset on resize

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm using GSAP / Tweenmax for some animations and I'm very close to where I want the animations to be. I have two different timelines - one for mobile, one for desktop. How can I make sure they each play regarding the window width and also if screen is resized clear to the final state of each animation. I tried using some window width resize calls but now the animations play everytime the browser width is moved at all and I see why with how I'm calling the functions, what is the best way to do this? thanks! :)

js:

```
 $(function () {


    function animations() {
      if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        heroAnimation.play(0);
      }   else {
        heroAnimation.pause(0);
      }
    }

    function animationsMobile() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        heroAnimationMobile.play(0);
      }   else {
        heroAnimationMobile.pause(0);
      }
    }

    $(window).resize(animations);
    animations();

    $(window).resize(animationsMobile);
    animationsMobile();

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep track of the state and only restart the animation if the state changes. Also only use one function, no need for two:

```
var state = "";
function animations() {
  var newState = state;
  if (innerWidth > 768) {
    newState = "big";
  } else {
    newState = "small";
  }

  if(newState !== state) {
    if(newState === "big") {
      heroAnimation.play(0);
      heroAnimationMobile.pause(0);
    } else {
      heroAnimation.pause(0);
      heroAnimationMobile.play(0);
    }

    state = newState;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("resize", animations);
animations();
```

By the way, you should totally use [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3/)! It has a smaller file size, sleeker API, and a bunch of new features!

Also, you're more likely to get an even faster response and additional insight over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Comment: NIce! I've been reading the docs and experimenting, really digging it so far...I appreciate the insight